# How to sort a dataframe/pivot-table by a distinct count of subcategory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to sort the first column of a data-frame by the distinct count of the second column corresponding to the first column value.

Un-sorted data from pivot-table:

```
investor  company round roundSize
investor1   Foo     A      10
investor2   Bar     A      10
            Foo     A      10
investor3   Bar     A      10
                    B      15
investor4   Bar     B      15
            Baz     C      100
            Foo     A      10
```

Post-sorting, the table should be:

```
investor  company round roundSize
investor4   Bar     B      15
            Baz     C      100
            Foo     A      10
investor2   Bar     A      10
            Foo     A      10
investor3   Bar     A      10
                    B      15
investor1   Foo     A      10
```

Here, the column 2 (company) distinct count for investor4 is 3, so investor4 and matching values should be at the top.

investor3 & investor1 both have a count of 2, it would be great to apply a secondary (but not necessary) sort to the count of round, or average of roundSize.

I'm quite new to python/pandas - but I'm struggling to find an example of where this has been applied. The pandas documentation is good, but doesn't quite touch this type of problem.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/reshaping.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the index to have the pivot table take shape of a DataFrame

```
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
    investor company round  roundSize
0  investor1     Foo     A         10
1  investor2     Bar     A         10
2  investor2     Foo     A         10
3  investor3     Bar     A         10
4  investor3     Bar     B         15
5  investor4     Bar     B         15
6  investor4     Baz     C        100
7  investor4     Foo     A         10
```

Create `sort index` and sort by that column

```
>>> df['sort_idx'] = df.groupby('investor')['company'].transform('nunique')
>>> df.sort_values('sort_idx', ascending=False)
    investor company round  roundSize  sort_idx
5  investor4     Bar     B         15         3
6  investor4     Baz     C        100         3
7  investor4     Foo     A         10         3
1  investor2     Bar     A         10         2
2  investor2     Foo     A         10         2
0  investor1     Foo     A         10         1
3  investor3     Bar     A         10         1
4  investor3     Bar     B         15         1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! 

I found that on larger/real data sets this did not always keep investor data grouped together, ie the last three rows could be: 

investor3
investor1
investor3

This is easily fixed with: 
`df.sort_values(by=['sort_idx','Investor'], ascending=False)`